# Migrating from Catrthrob to Expresso

Tags: expresso-store, cartthrob, migration

Has anyone migrated from CartThrob to Expresso Store ?
I have a site using cart throb and we need sales (specials) functionality. This is not handled very will is CartThrob, but Expresso does it nicely.
So, we are looking to swap carts.
I was wondering if anyone had done this, and what their experiences (traps, problems, etc) were.

Answer (score 0):

That all depends on how complex your products are, and how big your product catalogue is.

Obviously you'll have to rewrite a lot of template code - but since CartThrob and Store both store their order data differently, you can preserve all your old CartThrob orders with ease. (If you were looking to import that data into Store that's a different story.)

The main thing will be moving your products over - you can keep the same product entries, but you'll need to add a Store fieldtype to that channel, and then run  a migration to insert price and stock data into the various `exp_store_` tables. If you have simple products, this is not a big deal. If you have products with multiple options via the CartThrob Options fieldtype, then you have to decode that data, format it, and insert those options as well.

Your best bet is to install Store, then manually add your options to an existing product. You can then look at the various Store database tables and see how products, options, and stock were added so you can plan a programmatic migration.

Comment: Hey Derek, thanks for the response. Thats a good help.